# How to pass custom parameters to Django Custom RelatedField Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have written a Custom relational Field

```
class CustomField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        
        print(self.context)

        return {
            'id': obj.test_id,
            'name': obj.test_name,
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            try:
                return self.get_queryset().get(test_id=data)
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id is a required field.'
                )
            except ValueError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id must be an integer.'
                )
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'Obj does not exist.'
            )
```

This is how the CustomField is used

```
    sample_field = CustomField(queryset=SampleModel.objects.all())
```

If I want to pass additional parameters that will be later accessed like self.var in the to_representation and to_internal_value functions of the CustomField, how should I do that?

Comment: You can add anything to the `context` which is available in the entire process. Wouldn't that enough?

Comment: adding to the context gives the following error:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Comment: I think I figured it out, I can just override the __init__ method and initialize the variables there. I will fix the code and write an answer if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrode the `__init__()` function to set custom parameters needed for to_representation to_internal_value functions. This is the code for it

```
class CustomField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id_field = kwargs.pop('id_field', None)
        name_field = kwargs.pop('name_field', None)
        
        super(CustomField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id_field = id_field
        self.name_field = name_field        

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        
        print(self.context)

        return {
            'id': getattr(obj,self.id_field),
            'name': getattr(obj,self.name_field),
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            try:
                return self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id is a required field.'
                )
            except ValueError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id must be an integer.'
                )
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'Obj does not exist.'
            )
```

I can now use this CustomField like this:

```
sample_field = CustomField(queryset=SampleModel.objects.all(),id_field="test_id",name_field="test_name")
```